# /ipad/i.test() how syntax works?

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax

I am new to `/ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())` syntax. I know the results it returns true for ipad and false for remaining browsers.

please any body explain `/ipad/i` what it means and how it works

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a simpler breakdown of `/ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())`:

```
var myRegex = new RegExp("ipad", "i");;
var result = myRegex.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
```

Here `RegExp` is the [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) of JavaScript's RegExp object.

It creates a regular expression to match `ipad` string using the `i` flag which tells the RegExp object to ignore case of the string to be matched. [Regular expressions are patterns used to match character combinations in strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Then the `test()` method of RegExp is called and browser's useragent string in being passed to it. The test() method tries to match the useragent string with `ipad`, if found `true` will be returned. **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8mzTE/**.

[A user-agent string identifies your browser and provides its details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms537503.aspx):

> When you visit a webpage, your browser sends the user-agent string to
>   the server hosting the site that you are visiting. This string
>   indicates which browser you're using, its version number, and details
>   about your system, such as operating system and version. The web
>   server can use this information to provide content that is tailored
>   for your specific browser.

In JavaScript, the useragent string can be accessed using `navigator.userAgent`.

Answer (score 8):

`/ipad/i` is a [JavaScript Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) literal that matches any string that contains `ipad` (the `i` at the end is an instruction to perform case insensitive comparision). The [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method returns true if there was a match.

Regular expressions are available in many languages (PERL, PHP, JavaScript etc) and they are primarily used to match strings against simple to complicated patterns.

[`navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.navigator) is a global object which contains information about the application running the script (e.g. the browser). [navigator.userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.userAgent) contains the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string. For iPads, the user agent string looks like:

> Mozilla/5.0 (**iPad**; CPU OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7
>   Safari/6533.18.5

You will notice that it conains the word "iPad" in it.

Comment: Yea, but what is "navigator.userAgent"?

Comment: @bjb568 a browser variable. paste it in your console

Answer (score 4):

`/ipad/i` is [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). `ipad` is taken literally, but the `i` will make the whole string case-insensitive. `.test` will [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) the given string to see if it satisfies the regex. `navigator.userAgent` is a string that browsers give identifying themselves (like "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25"). "toLowerCase" does exactly that.

Using both `/i` (case-insensitive), and toLowerCase is redundant. I suggest just using `navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') !== -1`, since iPad always has the same capitalization.